# Improve performance of Mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL procedure that updates records the cursor is selecting from.

The cursor table is about 30k records.

The purpose of the procedure is to convert a column in a product table that has categories separated by a "," such as  "100,172,366" to its descriptive  category hierarchy i.e. "CatLev1/CatLev2,CatLev1,CatLev1/CatLev2/CatLev3/CatLev4"

I know this is not ideal but the table is loaded via mysqlimport without data manipulation.

There could be just 1 or as many as 4 categories the product is found in this column.

The categories table represents a category hierarchy in such that a row has id, description, parent id.

The hierarchy could be up to 4 levels deep.

Currently the procure works but is very slow. I am looking for recommendations on how to improve its performance. It currently takes anywhere from 5-10 seconds per cursor record fetch

```
CREATE DEFINER=`remote`@`%` PROCEDURE `convert_categories`()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
DECLARE cat VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE prodsku VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE fullstr VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE newstr VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE tempstr VARCHAR(255);


declare cur cursor for select sku,categories from staging_product;


DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

open cur;

get_categories: LOOP

    fetch cur into prodsku, fullstr;
    IF done THEN 
        LEAVE get_categories;
    END IF;
    set a=0;
    set newstr ='';

    #loop through the categories separating each value and build the category hierarchy

     simple_loop: LOOP
        SET a=a+1;
        SET cat=SPLIT_STRING(",",fullstr,a);
        IF cat='' THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
        ELSE 
            SET tempstr = (SELECT MAX(concat_ws ('/',t1.desc, t2.desc, t3.desc, t4.desc))
            FROM staging_category AS t1
            LEFT JOIN staging_category AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.id
            LEFT JOIN staging_category AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.id
            LEFT JOIN staging_category AS t4 ON t4.parent_id = t3.id
                where t4.id = cat or t3.id = cat or t2.id = cat or t1.id = cat);

            IF a>1 THEN SET newstr = CONCAT(newstr,',',tempstr);
                ELSE SET newstr = tempstr;
            END IF;
        END IF;


    END LOOP simple_loop;
    # update the current record with the verbal categories and hierarchy

    update staging_product set staging_product.categories =newstr where staging_product.sku = prodsku;

end LOOP get_categories;

close cur;
END
```

Comment: Have you run EXPLAINs on the queries in your cursor loop to find out if the tables are indexed efficiently?

Comment: @bobwienholt I have not. Are you thinking on the cursor table or the hierarchy table?

Comment: Well, you are doing a full scan on the staging_product table with your cursor (since you need to visit every record), so I'm not concerned about that.  I would check that you have indexes on staging_category.parent_id and staging_product.sku since your inner queries would greatly benefit from them.

Comment: I do have an index on staging_product.sku but not staging_category.parent_id.  I will add one and see how we do.

Comment: hmmm didn't seem to increase the speed by much..maybe a second or two for each record.